# Unity: Have Camera scroll and not jump to a certain position

Tags: unity-game-engine

in my little platformer I have a character that can jump. If he jumps heigh enough, the camera is supposed to also follow the character upwards. If he isnt heigh enough, the camera stays on its Y axis and only follows the player via tha X axis. I have achieved this like so:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float posX = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.x, player.transform.position.x, ref velocty.x, smoothTimeX);
    float posY = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.y, (player.transform.position.y + OffSetY), ref velocty.y, smoothTimeY);

    if(player.transform.position.y > heightOfPlayerForCamFollow) // change camera hight only when player has reached certain height level
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, transform.position.z);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(posX, 0, transform.position.z);
    }


}
```

However, now, once the player has reached a certain jump height, the camera JUMPS to the position of the player instead of following him. Simply due to the fact, that I am giving it the players Y position. How would I adjust my code to get the camera to follow and not teleport to the player?

THank you :)

Comment: Well there is no way you can achieve this with this logic. Because you check how high player jumped by checking the position. Maybe you can change your logic. How does your player jump? What should the user do to jump high enough hold the `space` key or something?

Comment: Exactly, holding the space key it is. I though of maybe using a colision detection with a high up point in the sky but would that really change anything?

Comment: In my opinion you have to decide already when the space key is pressed if the player will jump high enough not when player reached certain destination. Then you can `lerp` to the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it seems that the best way to approach is to move the conditional to a different place. You can set you target Y value based on the if, but then interpolate using smoothdamp anyways, so it returns to 0 (or whatever your base value is) smoothly

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float posX = Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.x, player.transform.position.x, ref velocty.x, smoothTimeX);
    float yTarget=0;
    if(player.transform.position.y > heightOfPlayerForCamFollow) 
         yTarget=(player.transform.position.y + OffSetY) 
     else 
        yTarget=0;
    float posY =Mathf.SmoothDamp(transform.position.y, yTarget, ref velocty.y, smoothTimeY);
    transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, transform.position.z);


}
```

Comment: Hey thank you. This did what I asked for. However, and this is my fault - the camera now maintains the player in its center EVEN when he is high up in the sky. This results in the camera moving up EXTREMLY fast to keep the player in the center. What I would really want though, is, once the camera follows upwards, the keep the player not in center but further up. So that the player, as long as he is in within the height limit, remains on the top of the screen and then, once the camera is down again, the player falls back into center. Can you help me out once more? :)

Comment: isn't that what OffsetY is doing? also you can try increasing your smoothTimeY slightly - sometimes a small increase will give a much smoother movement. maybe having offsetY close to or equals heightOfPlayerForCamFollow would do the job? I haven't actually tested the code so while I am happy that it works, I am not sure how to improve it

Comment: offsetY is so that the player is not totally centered but a little further down. But maybe altering offsetY once the player is in the air. let me try...

Comment: Fantastic. Altering offsetY (I used it differently than you) but this totally did the trick. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{

    float prevY = transform.position.y;

    float step = followSpeed * Time.deltaTime;  // need to set followSpeed
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, step));

    if (player.transform.position.y < heightOfPlayerForCamFollow) {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, prevY, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey that sound good. but one issue: the camera now follows the player up, but then, once the player falls back down and reached a min position, the camera skips to the ground. But ofc I need it to also move downwards and not skip downwards.. but nearly there! :))

Comment: thank you. But this code leads to some odd res: The camera follows the player upwards but still skips down. Once I repeated this a few times the camera bugs out and starts to completely film some other place way off screen... cant erally tell you why though... :P

Comment: Try it now, I left out the y smoothing.

Comment: sorry, but it still doesnt follow the player back down ... just teleports down. up is fine :)

Comment: I thank you for your effort, however the camera still bugs out and moves on its own. It might be my fault but another guy gave a perfect answer. I will upvote because of your help. thank you my friend:)

Comment: Thanks, can't win em all eh?

Comment: I wish we could :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, transform.position.z);` to be a target position rather than setting it as the cameras position. Then continually LERP your camera's Y position towards this Y position.

So in a sort of pseudo code:

```
if(camera.pos.y = target.pos.y)
skip
else
camera.pos.y.MoveTowards(target.pos.y, 10%)
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html provides a nice function to interpolate between 2 values.